# Alternative Formulation of Arc Length

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, arc-length

> If $\gamma : [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}^n$ continuously differentiable, show that the arc length $arc(\gamma)$ equals $\sup \{ \sum_{i=1}^n ||\gamma (t_i)-\gamma (t_{i-1})|| \mid a = t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_n = b \}$.

Recall that $arc(\gamma ) = \int_{a}^{b} ||\gamma '(t)||dt$. I'm trying to solve the above problem. I've already shown that a sequence of points in $\{ \sum_{i=1}^n ||\gamma (t_i)-\gamma (t_{i-1})|| \mid a = t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_n = b \}$ converges to $arc (\gamma)$, so I just need to show that $arc (\gamma)$ is an upper bound of the set. I've reduced this to showing that $\int_{a}^{b} ||\gamma ' (t)|| dt \ge ||\gamma (b) - \gamma (a)||$ holds. Intuitively/geometrically it's obvious, but I having trouble mathematizing my intuition. I could use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have essentially solved this already. $$ |\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)| =  \left| \int_a^b \gamma'(t) \, dt \right|  \le \int_a^b |\gamma'(t)| \, dt $$

by the triangle inequality. This is another version of the Mean Value Theorem, summarisable as: "global growth $\le$ local growth".

Comment: I thought that the mean value theorem didn't hold for vector valued functions.

Comment: I think you only need it to hold component by component. Anyway the above argument based on the triangle inequality is correct, vector or not.

Comment: I don't see how component by component will help, since we'll get a different value of $t$ in the mean value function for each coordinate function. As a matter of fact, the mean value theorem doesn't hold: $\gamma : [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}^2$ defined by $\gamma (t) = (t,t^2)$ is a counterexample,

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing. You're using FOTC, which does hold for vector-valued functions. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: No probs, I didn't do a very good job of explaining it, and I could have omitted my comment about the MVT, which might have been better.

Comment: (I've seen this called the 'mean value inequality')